# How to fix error, File ended while scanning use of \@cline error

Tags: tables, cline

hi I have this code

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-7}
 & Windows Forms & PDF & Windows Forms/GDI+ & Windows Media Player & Direct3D & \textbf{WPF} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Grafické rozhranie} & X &  &  &  &  & \textbf{X} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Dokumenty na obrazovke} & X &  &  &  &  & \textbf{X} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Dokumenty s pevným,formátom} &  & X &  &  &  & \textbf{X} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Obrázky} &  &  & X &  &  & \textbf{X} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Video a zvuk} &  &  &  & X &  & \textbf{X} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2D grafika} &  &  & X &  &  & \textbf{X} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3D grafika} &  &  &  &  & X & \textbf{X} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}`
```

and I have this error

> File ended while scanning use of \@cline

Can you help me pls?

Comment: I'm sorry, this code (completed) compiles fine. Could you post a minimal complete example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Testing your code within `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\end{document}` compiles without issue for me... although the table doesn't fit the page at all.

Comment: for me, without `\cline{2-7}` it is working ... but with this nope

Comment: Perhaps you have `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` or `\usepackage[slovak]{babel}`, can you confirm?

Answer (score 2):

I am also unable to reproduce the error message you say you're getting. At any rate, I'd like to suggest that get rid of the `\cline` instruction and modify your table to give it a much more open look, by (a) getting rid of all vertical lines, (b) getting rid of most of the horizontal lines generated by `\hline`, and (c) using the macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` of the [booktabs](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package for the remaining horizontal lines.

Moreover, in order to give the table a fighting chance to fit insde the text block, I would further like to suggest that you use a `tabularx` environment with an overall width of `\textwidth` and use automatic line wrapping for three of the six data columns.

A final comment: What might be the purpose of boldfacing all entries in the final column?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page size parameters

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
% define a centered version of the "X" column type
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l CcCCcc @{}}
\toprule
 & Windows Forms & PDF & Windows Forms\slash GDI+ & 
  Windows Media Player & Direct3D & \textbf{WPF} \\ 
\midrule
Grafické rozhranie & X &  &  &  &  & \textbf{X} \\ 
Dokumenty na obrazovke & X &  &  &  &  & \textbf{X} \\ 
Dokumenty s pevným, formátom &  & X &  &  &  & \textbf{X} \\ 
Obrázky &  &  & X &  &  & \textbf{X} \\ 
Video a zvuk &  &  &  & X &  & \textbf{X} \\ 
2D grafika &  &  & X &  &  & \textbf{X} \\ 
3D grafika &  &  &  &  & X & \textbf{X} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

Postscript: Happily, this code is compatible with the `babel` package and the use of either the `czech` or the `slovak` language option.

Comment: I assumed the boldface in the final column is there because that is the most important point. Personally, I'd be using a light non-intrusive colour that highlates the column without smacking you in the face with **Look at ME!** ("colour" meaning light grey [`black!25` at most] or something like that)

Comment: @BMWurm - Your guess seems on target. If "WPF" is indeed the most important part of the table, though, I'd move it to the *first* data column, rather than place it last. The idea of highlighting the entire WPF column with a not-too-obtrusive color -- and not using bold-facing -- is also worth pursuing.